# Clicking on items as soon as they are visible

Tags: python

I would like to ask if in python it can be set to click on an element if it is visible instead of putting time.sleep between clicking on elements

Comment: provide a [mre] and be more specific

Comment: Are you talking about Selenium? The question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about selenium then use WebDriverWait function.

It can be used as:

```
WebDriverWait(<webdriver>, <delay>).until(lambda x: x.find_element(<element-to-find>))
```

where webdriver is your selenium webdriver and delay is the time till which it'll check for the occurrence of the element or raise an error afterwards.

It can be imported by

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```